# Python, flask, Ubuntu: Требования к серверу для 1.000 / 10.000 пользователей одновременно? Нужен ли SingleTone?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, flask

Разработали приложение, используя Python 3.7, flask (конечно WSGI-mode), bootsrap, AJax. Приложение установленно Ubuntu 16.04, Apache. Все нормально работает. Может кто-нибудь подсказать:

1) Как определить требования к серверу что бы он выдержал 1.000 / 10.000 пользователей одновременно?

2) Будет ли падать сервер из-за того что мы не пользуемся SingleTone? Нужно ли создавать SingleTone или использовать что-то другое для оптимизации пула соеденинений (к примеру PgBouncer)?  Или для нашего числа соединений об этом можно не беспокоиться?

Данные лежат в postgreSQL. Для работы с базой данных (PostgerSQL) использовался простой код:

==

```
pg_conn = psycopg2.connect(db_url)
cur = pg_conn.cursor()
cur.execute(my_sql)
...
...
...
pg_conn.close()
```

==

Comment: Для 10 000 одновременно - переписать приложение на асинхронном фреймворке.